# mouseover on float element didn't fire when the next element is in relative position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the mouseover event that is not triggered on a floating element because the next element has a `position: relative;` !

Here is a demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/7UjQZ/

Indeed, the element with a `position: relative` seems to go over the floating element and catch the mouseover event. When I remove the `position: relative`, there is no longer a problem! Unless I absolutely have to this property because in my initial problem I have elements inside width absolute position.

Do you have any idea? A solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7UjQZ/1/)

It's a `z-index` issue:

Update you CSS to have higher `z-index` for `.float`:

```
.float
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellowgreen;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading about [relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning#Relative_positioning).

See what happens when we use the relative position in your code. I added the background for a better experience.

```
.text {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7UjQZ/2/